# jQuery - Appending images after input field based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Firstly here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/ru80sfwf/)

I'm trying to append an image after input field, the input field can be selected based on value.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="example"> Example
```

JS Code:

```
 $('input[value="example"]').append("<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/nav_logo195.png'");
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.after()`, instead of `.append()`. The `.append()` method inserts the new element as the last child of the element it is called on, whereas `.after()` inserts the new element after the element it is called on.

```
$('input[value="example"]').after("<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/nav_logo195.png'/>");
```

You were also missing the following characters at the end of your string: `/>`

Comment: Thank you John for the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div id="id">
   <input type="checkbox" value="bigstock">Big store
</div>
```

js:

```
html="<img src='https://www.google.co.in/images/nav_logo195.png'>";
$('#id').append(html).trigger("create");
```

The jsfiddle link for reference:

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/san_here/y6r78mgy/
```

Hope, it will usefull.

Comment: Thank you san for the answer.